# I am unable to make a http call while running my ionic v4 app in browser

Tags: http, ionic4

I want to run my Ionic 4 app in browser and make a http post request. The request is sent, when the app is running on a mobile device but it doesn't work in the browser.

```
 this.http.post(
    url, 
    { 
        "req": 2, 
        "userId": username, 
        "password": password, 
        "orgId": 1, 
        "device_id": "", 
        "device_type": "android", 
        "regd_id": "", 
        "build_type": "production"
    },
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    ).then(async data => { 
        //some logic
    }).catch(error => {
        //Error Handling
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the plugin [cordova-plugin-advanced-http](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http)

and used the code:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
```

It not posible running this on browser because is a function that use native http of device, the same browser say that on console.

[image]

If you want to use on browser need to use:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

If you want to run the app in parallel (mobile/browser) need to import both plugin and use the plugin [Platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/platform) and use the code to use the correspondent:

this.platform.is("ios" || "android" || "desktop")

I'm not sure about the platform names that return the plugin but do test to know it.

[image: platform names]

I hope I've helped :)

Comment: Hey Macro, thanks for the solution, but it still didn't help, as I am getting ERROR STATUS: 500 ("INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"). I have handled the CORS error too. I imported -  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; and accessed it using the snippet: 
this.http.post(url, data1, requestOptions)
.subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
console.log(data['_body']);
}, error => {
console.log(error);
});

Comment: Error status 500 is an issue of server self, I don't know if you have control of the server, I apologize but I don't have knowledge about that, I had that problem once and was resolved for the backend team did a configuration of server and there was no more problem. Maybe you need create a different post for that.